# Subgradient of function $f_p(\mathbf{A})$ that has as output the $p^{th}$ largest singular value

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matrix-norms, matrix-analysis

Suppose I have a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.  Let $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,.....,\sigma_n \}$ be its $n$ singular values. Calculating a sub-gradient of  its operator norm (largest singular value) is a well known result. Are more general results available i.e can we find the sub-gradient of the function ( of the matrix $A$) that produces as output the second largest singular value, third largest singular value and generally p-th largest singular value ($p=1,2,...,n$). Is it a well posed question at all.

Comment: What do you mean by subgradient of an eigenvalue?

Comment: I meant , if we treat the $p-th$ largest singular value as a function of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Once we have a function of the matrix, then we can talk about subgradients of that function. I edited the question to reflect your question

Answer (score 1):

As an application of the [Min-Max Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) You get
$$\sigma_{j+1}=\min_{x_1,..,x_j\in\mathbb{R}^n}\quad\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n||x||=1\\(x,x_1)=...=(x,x_j)=0}||Ax||.$$
As You see for $j=0$ you get $\sigma_1=|||A|||$ where $|||.|||$ is the operator norm. Of course the singular values are numbered in non-increasing order.Here $j=0,..,n-1$. The result can be generalized to ( possibly infinite-dimensional) Hilbert-spaces and compact operators.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Melech. If I understand correctly, the above formulation expresses each of the singular values as  an optimization problem. But does this formulation help us in finding the sub-gradient of function $f_p(\mathbf{A})$

Comment: As far as I understand it [sub-gradient methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgradient_method) are a kind of methods solving optimization problems and as far as I can see it, these optimization problems, that the Min-max Theorem yields, would be those that one should try to solve by sub-gradients.@Engineer_2018

Comment: Subgradient of a function is a generalization of the concept  of gradient to nonsmooth functions. My question asks how we can calculate one of those subgradients ( as it is a set ). Thanks for the suggestion, I will check if the min max theorem can lead to any subgradients

Comment: Good luck! At least $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n :||x||=1,(x,x_1)=...=(x,x_j)=0\}$ is convex for $j=0,...,n-1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.@Peter Melech